# UISearchDisplayController with more than one search term

Tags: ios, xcode, search, nspredicate, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I wonder if there is any way to search for more than one word using UISearchDisplayController? If I for example want to search for posts containing both "James" AND "London"? Or "James" and "Smith"?

I have searched but not found an answer to this.

This is what I do now, to see if the search term is in either the name or address.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSMutableArray *searchItemsPredicate = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    [searchItemsPredicate addObject:namePredicate];
    NSPredicate *addressPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"address contains[c] %@", searchText];
    [searchItemsPredicate addObject:addressPredicate];
    NSCompoundPredicate *combinedPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:searchItemsPredicate];

    searchResults = [_array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:combinedPredicate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to separate each words.
You can use a `NSRegularExpression` or use simply `componentsSeparatedByString:` (to keep it simple).

```
NSArray *words = [searchText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSMutableArray *allPredicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *aWord in words)
{
     NSPredicate *addressPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"address contains[c] %@", aWord];
     NSPredicate *namePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", aWord];
    [allPredicates addObject:addressPred];
    [allPredicates addObject:namePred];
}

NSCompoundPredicate *finalPredicate = [[NSCompoundPredicate alloc] initWithType: NSOrPredicateType subPredicates:allPredicates];

searchResults = [_array filteredArrayUsingPredicate: finalPredicate];
```

You can use a more complexe scheme for your "words limitations" (comma, etc.) to mark delimitations for example:
Searching @"Banana, Apple fruit" could be in fact looking for "words" : @"Banana" and @"Apple fruit", in that case the separator string would be "," (and you may have to trim for white spaces).